# Why is mysql not adding a point to the point column?

Tags: mysql

CODE:

```
UPDATE tbl_name
    SET points = points + 1
    WHERE 'GAME 1' LIKE "%Vikes%"
```

The column GAME 1 contains rows containing either Vikes or Saints all the points are currently at 0, why wont my code add a point? Thanks

Comment: A schema like this is a pretty blatant violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You should have a row per game that's associated with the "home" and "away" teams, or have two score rows per game, anything but this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not referring to the *column* `Game 1`.  It is referring to the string `'Game 1'`.  And that string is not like the comparison string.

This is probably what you want:

```
UPDATE tbl_name
    SET points = points + 1
    WHERE `GAME 1` LIKE '%Vikes%';
```

The escape character for identifiers are the backticks.

That said, the correct advice is to avoid using non-standard characters in identifiers.  Just use letters, numbers, and underscore, so the name does not need to be escaped.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, what are the names of the characters next to GAME 1?